# What to do with this bending mulberry tree

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, tree-care, mulberry

I live in northern Mississippi. My mulberry tree is tipping a lot. Should I just get a pole and tie it to it or do something else?

[image]

Comment: Yes you should bang in a stake and tie it to the stake.